# where is the database icon in the symfony 1.4.8 debug toolbar?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I recently upgraded to SF 1.4.8 on Linux.

However, I cant seem to find the Db icon in the toolbar, so I can't check my queries etc.

I am using the Propel ORM. Has the db icon been removed from the toolbar?. It seems to be there as recently as v 1.4.3

Answer (score 6):

May be you have disabled the profiler in database.yml :

```
  dev:
    doctrine:
      class: sfDoctrineDatabase
        param:
          profiler: false
```

This code also disabled the icon in the debugbar...

Answer (score 1):

If you have some queries , you can see icon like in screenshot.In 1.4.8 It same as in 1.4.11. But I use doctrine.

[**ScreenShot**](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/847/unled1de.png/)